# extra bytes in malloc allocation

Tags: c, malloc

I have this path:
./demodir/a1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1

When I allocate the space for the path name in a string using just one (1) extra byte (for the '\0') the string prints differently.

```
path = (char *) malloc( strlen(dirname) + strlen(direntp->d_name) + 1 );
```

Prints:
./demodir/a1!�/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1

� .... is the issue

I need to all "+2" bytes to the memory allocation, besides the length of the content.. Why is that?

Comment: Firstly, the code you posted does not "print" anything, so how it can possibly "print" what you posted is not clear. Secondly, I don't see any code that would initialize the memory you allocated. Where is it?

Comment: Where has `dirname` come from? Console input? That strange character `'�'` suggests more than not enough string length. Is it the EOF value as a character?

Comment: Hmmmm... Which encoding is your path? Are you sure there is no wide char UTF8 in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the extra byte to include the slash '/' separating the dirname from the basename.

```
char  *path = (char *) malloc( strlen(dirname) + 1 + strlen(direntp->d_name) + 1 );  
sprintf(path, "%s/%s", dirname, dirent->d_name)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: No prob. We've all made that mistake (which is how I recognized the omission)